# Power 12V DC Motor with 16.8V (4S Lipo) using PWM control mechanism

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, step-up

I have recently completed a DIY robot that uses 2x 18650 cells (max 8.4V) and a step up module to power four 12V DC motors (Pololu 20d). For my next prototype, I would like to get rid of the step up module because from my point of view, it seems like a possible point of failure that is not needed. Is it possible to use four 18650 (max 16.8V) and directly power the motors from them? My plan is to use a Teensy Microcrontroller that measures the battery voltage using a voltage divider and then applies a PWM signal to the motors so the voltage for the motors would not exceed 12V. 
Example: the battery voltage is 16.8V and the motors should turn at full speed. The Teensy would therefore apply a PWM signal of 182 ((182/255) * 16.8 = 12. 
Would this technique damage the motors?

Comment: I suggest using 3 batteries, and omit the PWM circuit.

Comment: Yeah I also thought of that but 3x 18650 would equal a max voltage of 12.6V and a minimum voltage of about 10.5V (I usually don't let the batteries drain below 3.5V per cell). Since my motor driver has an internal voltage drop of 0.6V, the voltage range for the motors would be 9.9-12V which would result in a change in speed as the batteries drain. Since I don't really use the motors at full speed, I suppose I could use some kind of control logic that limits the max voltage for the motors to 10V, so their speed won't change if the batteries drain. What do you think about it?

Comment: If it is important to you that the motor runs at a constant speed, then you will need to regulate the voltage somehow, either using PWM as you suggested or a voltage regulator.  The 12V Pololu motors can run between 6 and 12V (stated on their website).  

I don't know if applying 16V will damage the motors.  If you use PWM such that the average is close to 12V, then probably not would be my guess.  

Your PWM circuit will probably require some trial and error to get the frequency and duty cycle correct.  

Do you know how you will switch the voltage to the motor?

Comment: I plan to use a microcontroller in combination with a L293D H-bridge. My initial question was whether applying 12V to the motors using a PWM Signal and an initial voltage of 16V would damage the motors in the long-term

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought you meant.  The answer is: I don't know.  My opinion:  if you make sure you are always applying PWM to limit the average voltage, then it will probably fine.  Applying 16VDC (no PWM) would likely overstress the motors.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, DC motors can be PWM'd to reduce the effective voltage. However, you need to choose a suitable PWM rate.

Too slow, and the motor will judder, as the current and hence torque swings excessively.

Too fast, and the armature iron, which will probably not have been designed with high frequency PWM in mind, will suffer high eddy current losses, heating the motor and reducing efficiency (it will have been designed for operation at the rotational frequency of the motor). Switching losses in your driver are proportional to PWM frequency as well.

The idea then is to run at as low a PWM frequency as possible, while the keeping the current and so torque continuous and reasonably smooth, check it with an oscilloscope if you have one. If you are PWM'ing in the audio range, the motor is likely to sing, you may want to go to above 20 kHz if this is a problem in your application.